# Re-Render my RecyclerView causes Slowness

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

I've an 
Activity A that i run a Get (from HttpOk) and send the itens to an RecyclerView.
Everything runs fine on first time: onCreate, Start, Resume, Etc..
So, the user select itens that he want "buy", and i pass this, via Intent (JSONObject.toString):

```
 startActivity(
     new Intent(this, CompraCreditoAVista.class)
        .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
        .putExtra("fromListaProdutos", true)
        .putExtra("infos", infosVenda)
        .putExtra("total", total)
 );
this.finish();
```

But, after that, when i start another Intent from one activity before that who contains the RecyclerView, ex: put a button on CompraCreditoAVista to repeat the action (or pass the same arguments to onBackPressed() of CompraCreditoAVista) the app become slower, the recyclerView takes 3-4x times to load, and the functions like change screen (another intents) becomes slower too.

After NEW_TASK / CLEAR_TASK (and finish()) it was for the activity takes the same time that he takes on the first time rendered no?

Comment: If the Activity IS finishing then I don't think its precisely because of what you're thinking it is. It sounds to me like you should just use a debugger. For all anyone knows, your second use causes some long running loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the tag on activity:

`android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`

is what cause the slowness on my app, why? even i don't know.